# Data connection refreshes; an identical data connection does not

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a spreadsheet with two worksheets, both of which contain a table populated by a data connection that queries an SQLServer database. As far as I can tell the two data connections are identical. One table can be refreshed, but refreshing the other gives an error "We couldn't refresh the connection 'audbbicube compass3'. The table 'compass3 Query' may not exist."

The settings displayed in Connection Properties for the two are identical except for one tick-box. The connection string for both is:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=audbbicube;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=AU-H7PYJX1;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=ion
```

Command Type for both is `SQL` and the Command Text for both is:

```
exec sp_letters_from_church 'CH2BAR', 'Menai', '2013-12-31', 5
```

Authentication for both is `Use the authenticated user's account`.

The data connection that works has `Enable background refresh` ticked. In the Connection Settings dialog for the one that does not work, `Enable background refresh` is unticked and greyed-out.

Q1: what would cause `Enable background refresh` to be greyed-out?

Q2: why would that make the data connection fail to refresh at all?

Q3: how do I fix it?

Comment: Since they're identical, why do you need both?

Comment: Good question. It's a debugging process. I had one working but when I opened the spreadsheet today it no longer worked. That is a pattern that has happened several times. So while investigating the problem I created a second connection from scratch -- one that worked -- and then tried to locate what the difference is. I fear that replacing the non-working one with the working one will lead to the same problem tomorrow or the next day. So I want to figure out what's causing the problem.